# He can't / mustn't have been looking where he was going

Tags: modal-verbs

> Tom walked into a wall. He *can't* have been looking where he was going.

a) Can I use *mustn't* instead of *can't* here? ("He *mustn't* have been looking where he was going.")

b) If I use *couldn't* instead of *can't* here, will it decrese the probability of my supposition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered a similar question of yours here:
[He mustn't/couldn't have been](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/7522/1694)

To answer succinctly your question, you can use **can't have** and **couldn't have** indifferently.

I know that online there are websites that infer *can't have* = 99% certainty, whereas *mustn't have* (which is non-standard English)= 95%
[can't have vs.couldn't have](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00108.htm) But how do you measure 99%? And why is *mustn't* fixed at 95%?

> b) If I use couldn't instead of can't here, will it decrease the
>   probability of my supposition?

When speaking, listeners will understand how certain you are by your facial expressions and voice intonation. Some will argue that using *couldn't* tentatively increases uncertainty. I think this is subjective, there is no fixed rule. Use whichever you're most comfortable with, and that includes *mustn't have*

If however, you are planning to sit an exam in the future, choose between *can't have* or *couldn't have* in your writing. Every time.