# Word choice between can't and couldn't

Tags: word-choice, difference, usage

> He ***can't/couldn't*** be the wanted man.
>
> It ***can't/couldn't*** have been true.

*Why are **can't** and **couldn't** alternative in cases above?*

---

> Alex ***can't have broken*** that window because he never came anywhere near
>   here yesterday.

- In this sentence, could ***can't*** be replaced by ***couldn't*** ? Is there anything to do with the tense concord?
- *What's the difference between **can't have done** and **couldn't have done** ?*

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/7518/he-cant-mustnt-have-been-looking-where-he-was-going/7524#7524

Comment: I touch on this in my answer to your [other question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9042/difference-between-might-and-could).

Answer (score 1):

In those short sentences you give as examples, they can be interchangeable for normal, everyday use.  That they are interchangeable here could be due to insufficient context around the sentences. Can versus could is more subtle than may versus might, or can versus may.   Could is more subjunctive, tentative, but can is more firm - at least in this context.

Comment: As a follow up, wonder if our British speaking friends have a different take on this ?